# How to skip form validation from composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a composite component for user to confirm delete action. But the problem is when user clicks "Yes", Program tries to validate other inputfields at my form. I think immediate attribute doesn't working. How can i skip other input fields at my form?

My view;

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton id="myButtonId" onclick="deleteDialog.show();" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete"/>
//someinputfields and validators
<bzn:deleteConfirmDialog actionListener="#{addressBookController.deleteParty()}">
        </bzn:deleteConfirmDialog>

    </h:form>
```

here is my composite component;

```
<composite:interface>       

    <composite:attribute name="actionListener" 
                         method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />

</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <p:dialog id="deleteDialogId"                  
              widgetVar="deleteDialog"
              resizable="false"
              height="100"
              width="250"
              >
        <p:outputPanel>                
            <center>
                <p:commandButton value="Yes" immediate="true"
                                 actionListener="#{cc.attrs.actionListener}"
                                 oncomplete="deleteDialog.hide();"/>
                <p:commandButton value="No" oncomplete="deleteDialog.hide();"/>
            </center>
        </p:outputPanel>

    </p:dialog>

</composite:implementation>
```

Answer (score 2):

All inputs/buttons which belongs to one form must be placed in its own `<h:form>`.

In other words, don't use "God" forms. Give the dialog its own `<h:form>` (and make sure that it isn't nested in another `<h:form>`).

Basically,

```
<h:form>
    ...
</h:form>

<p:dialog>
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Note that this has **nothing** to do with composite components. You'd have had exactly the same problem when putting everything together in one view in SSCCE flavor ([which you should preferably already have done before posting the question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)).

By the way, the `<center>` element is deprecated since HTML 4.01 in 1998. I'm not sure where you learned HTML, but I recommend to look for up to date resources, prefarably never older than ~3 years.

Comment: "immediate=true" solved my problem. I am using update-process attributes so I think I don't need different forms in a page.

Comment: That's not a solution. That's a workaround. Like, you can also fasten a screw with a hammer, but that's not a solution. In developer terms, you've there just a bad design.